# Laravel 5 Override a class method

Tags: php, overriding, laravel-5

I would like to override the method `setContent()` of the class `Illuminate\Http\Response` as :

```
<?php 
namespace MyNameSpace\MyClass;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
class myResponse extends Reponse {
   public function setContent($content)
     // Something
   }
}
```

But I don't know how to tell Laravel to load my class instead of the original one.

Answer (score 2):

Too late, but as i came up with same issue. but for reference i would want to post how i resolved this issue.

When i wanted to handle all the the response by myself without using a response macro or transformer and **TO OVERRIDE MANY OTHER FRAMEWORK DEFAULT METHODs** . this is how i completely took control of the response object.

> just posted here for reference as i in my opinion it solves the
>   problem in a clearer way.

Lot of overriding as its done through pipeline and routing and so it`s registered as base service provider. here is how i managed to override all.

> here I am using laravel 5.3

1 - create a new response class

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\Illuminate\Http;

// use Illuminate\Http\Response as BaseResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as BaseResponse;

class Response extends BaseResponse
{
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        //do what ever you want to do with the content
        //dd($content);
    }
}
```

2 - create a new router and use the new response

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\Illuminate\Routing;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router as IlluminateRouter;
use App\Extensions\Illuminate\Http\Response;

class Router extends IlluminateRouter
{

    public function prepareResponse($request, $response)
    {
        if ($response instanceof PsrResponseInterface) {
            $response = (new HttpFoundationFactory)->createResponse($response);
        } elseif (! $response instanceof SymfonyResponse) {
            $response = new Response($response);
        }

        return $response->prepare($request);
    }
}
```

3 - create new routing service provider use new router

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Extensions\Illuminate\Routing\Router;


class RoutingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected function registerRouter()
    {
        $this->app['router'] = $this->app->share(function ($app) {
            return new Router($app['events'], $app);
        });
    }
}
```

4 - create new Application class and use new routing service provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions\Illuminate\Foundation;

use Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as App;
use App\Providers\RoutingServiceProvider;

class Application extends App
{
    protected function registerBaseServiceProviders()
    {
        $this->register(new EventServiceProvider($this));

        $this->register(new RoutingServiceProvider($this));
    }
}
```

5 - and finally in **bootstrap\app.php** use the new Application

```
// $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
//     realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
// );
$app = new App\Extensions\Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the [`Response` facade](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Response.php) to reflect the class you have, then change your [applications `/config/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L187) to link to your new facade rather than laravels.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work, maybe because it's not a facade, i'm trying to override "Illuminate\Http\Response" not "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request"

Comment: The `Facade` is the access point to the `Response` object, that's what laravel uses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a facade like so

```
<?php namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response as BaseResponse;

class Response extends BaseResponse {

    public static function overwriteMethod()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Then go to config/app.php under facades comment out this line

```
//'Response'  => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
```

Then add this to the facades stack

```
'Response'  => 'App\Facades\Response',
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work, maybe because it's not a facade, i'm trying to override "Illuminate\Http\Response" not "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request"